# When will IronWorkers support Ruby 2.0?

Tags: iron.io, ironworker

The default language version for ruby on IronWorkers is 1.9.3. When will it be bumped to 2.0?

http://dev.iron.io/worker/reference/environment/#default_languages_versions

Is there an easy way to upgrade to ruby 2.0 without too much delay when launching a task?

Thanks,
Dimitri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iron Worker is finally supporting custom environments, one of which is Ruby 2.1:
http://blog.iron.io/2014/03/ironio-launches-custom-runtime.html

Comment: To use ruby 2.1 in your .worker file add to your .worker file the following: 
stack 'ruby-2.1'

Answer (score 3):

[edit] You can now use multiple different language packs using our Stacks functionality as specified above. Also here's more info in the Iron.io dev center: http://dev.iron.io/worker/reference/environment/#default_language_versions

---

Currently no there is no way to use Ruby 2. We are working on a way to give users the ability to choose their language versions much easier, but there's no ETA at this point.

If you need any help or support don't hesitate to jump into our live chat http://get.iron.io/chat

Comment: Is this true even if you have remote build (`remote`) in your .worker file?

http://dev.iron.io/worker/reference/builds/#remote_build

Comment: Yes, currently there's a one size fits all environment. That should change very soon though.

Comment: Any updates on this?  Ruby 2.1 is out and we would like to move our infrastructure off 1.9.3, as it's no longer being updated with bug fixes.