# Send UrlFetchApp(url, options) request from Google Script to IronWorker

Tags: ruby, google-apps-script, iron.io

I am experimenting with connecting a Google Script to an IronWorker script.

Right now, I am just trying to get a "hello, world" level example to work.

My end goal is to pass data from Google Spreadsheets to an IronWorker for processing.

Right now, I just want to successfully POST to an IronWorker. Here's the Google Script function:

```
function myFunction() {
var arr = { "first" : "Chris", "last" : "Cruz" };
var url = 'https://worker-aws-us-east1.iron.io/2/projects/55c4f983e68185000600002b/tasks/webhook?code_name=hello-world-worker%3A%3Abuilder&oauth=mpPgu7iB0rT80iQ0mpCnCcy3nYE';
var options =
  {
    "method" : "post",
    "data"   : JSON.stringify(arr)
  }

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
Logger.log(response);
}
```

When I check the log in 'Hello, world»Workers»hello-world-worker::builder»Task #...10b44»Log', I see get this error output:

```
Successfully installed net-http-persistent-2.9.4
Successfully installed netrc-0.10.3
Successfully installed rest-3.0.6
Successfully installed iron_core-1.0.9
Successfully installed bundler-1.10.6
Successfully installed rubyzip-1.1.7
Successfully installed iron_worker_ng-1.6.6
7 gems installed
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:148:in `initialize': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:148:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
    from /mnt/task/__builder__.rb:47:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from __runner__.rb:224:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure where the error is being called from, so I don't know where to begin debugging. I'm running ruby version 2.0, and I did see this StackOverflow question: [When will IronWorkers support Ruby 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277327/when-will-ironworkers-support-ruby-2-0)

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the error output suggests it's a ruby problem.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workers, that postfixed with `::builder`, are "special". They build worker code package remotely (on IronWorker) for you. It happens, when you put `remote` directive to your `.worker` file. Actual worker name is `hello-world-worker`. So that, your webhook URL must looks like the following:

```
'https://worker-aws-us-east1.iron.io/2/projects/55c4f983e68185000600002b/tasks/webhook?code_name=hello-world-worker&oauth=<TOKEN>'
```

Replace `<TOKEN>` with your actual token. As you shared your current token, I suggest you to delete it and generate new. You can do that by clicking on your name at the top right corner of the HUD, and then on "My Tokens" menu item.